# difference between multiple dates based on id column in a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-datetime

My practical case is the following, in a store I would like to know visit period (in day) between the 1st visit and the 2nd visit, the 2nd and the 3rd,...

I have a python dataset with 2 columns (visit IDs for each customer and a date of visit)

```
data = {'Id': ['A', 'B','A','B','A','A'],
'Date': ['01/03/2022', '03/03/2022', '05/03/2022', '07/03/2022', '09/03/2022','11/03/2022']
}
```

[image]

My question : How many days are there between the 1st visit and the 2nd visit for  customers who have come 4 times? same question between the 2nd and the 3rd visit...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output you expect is unclear, but let's compute a 2D table with the customers as index and the visits as columns:

```
# convert to datetime (assuming DD/MM/YYYY)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)

# setting up group
g = df.groupby('Id')['Date']

df2 = (df
 .sort_values(by='Id')      # ensure the dates are ordered
 .assign(visit=g.cumcount().add(1),      # visit number
         nb_visits=g.transform('count'), # total number of visits
         diff=g.diff()                   # difference between successive visits
         )
 .query('nb_visits >= 4')   # filter to keep customers with at least 4 visits
 .pivot(index='Id', columns='visit', values='diff')  # reshape to 2D
)
```

output:

This gives the number of days since the previous visit for each customer (if more that 3 visits)

```
visit   1      2      3      4
Id                            
A     NaT 4 days 4 days 2 days
```

*NB. you could remove the first column here as it will always be undefined (NaT)*

Comment: @noliverte you're welcome, so is the 2D layout what you were looking for?

Comment: It's great, thank you for taking time to answer me. it works.
How can i improve your code to calculate mean of diff days for 2 visits for all customers(Id).
ie. out
visit         1          2               3           4            5
All Id       Nat     43 days   3 days   ....           ...

I try to delete .pivot..... in you code and calculate mean like that df2.groupby('nb_visits')['diff'].mean().T

how can i filter with visit=2     ?

Have a nice day

Comment: df_visit_delay_result=(df_visit_delay
    .sort_values(by='id_ctc') 
    .assign(visit=df_visit_delay_group.cumcount().add(1), 
            nb_visits=df_visit_delay_group.transform('count'), 
            diff=df_visit_delay_group.diff() 
            ).query('nb_visits>=4'))

Comment: df_visit_delay_result.groupby('visit')['diff'].mean().T

Answer (score 1):

You can first cast them to `pd.Timestamp` objects and sort the ids and dates by

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)
df = df.sort_values(['Id', 'Date'])
```

Then, you can simply calculate the difference in the timestamps, multiplied by the boolean mask of whether it is the same user:

```
df['Date Since Last Visit'] = (df['Date'] - df['Date'].shift(1)) * (df['Id'] == df['Id'].shift())
df['Date Since Last Visit'] = df['Date Since Last Visit'].fillna(pd.Timedelta(0))
```

Which will give you the timedelta objects that you can see how many days it has been.

Your output will be:

```
    Id  Date        Date Since Last Visit
0   A   2022-03-01  0 days
2   A   2022-03-05  4 days
4   A   2022-03-09  4 days
5   A   2022-03-11  2 days
1   B   2022-03-03  0 days
3   B   2022-03-07  4 days
```

Or just filter out the first visits after:

```
df['Date Since Last Visit'] = df['Date'] - df['Date'].shift(1)
df = df[df['Id'] == df['Id'].shift()]
```

Which gives you:

```
    Id  Date        Date Since Last Visit
2   A   2022-03-05  4 days
4   A   2022-03-09  4 days
5   A   2022-03-11  2 days
3   B   2022-03-07  4 days
```